# Como retornar un registro de una consulta sql desde java spring boot?

Tags: java, sql, angular, spring-boot, h2

En el día de hoy me encuentro buscando una solución de como podría calcular y sumas unas horas a los registros que tengo en mi base de datos H2 en el framework de spring.

Iniciando, tengo esta sentencia en sql`SELECT * FROM tech WHERE idTech=? AND (WEEK(horaInicio)=? OR WEEK(horaFinal)=?)`
Pero en esa sentencia deseo calcular cuantas horas hay de diferencia entre la hora de inicio y la hora final cierto, por lo cual agrego lo siguiente en el select, donde quedaria de la siguiente manera
`SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour,horaInicio,horaFinal) AS hours FROM tech WHERE idTech=? AND (WEEK(horaInicio)=? OR WEEK(horaFinal)=?)`

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, quisiera que en mi consulta pueda retornar esos valores al front, dado que estoy consumiendo la api desde angular 11.

El codigo de consultar es el siguiente

```
public List<Tech> findTechByIdTechAndWeek(String id, String week){
        String sql="SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour,horaInicio,horaFinal) AS hours FROM tech WHERE idTech=? AND (WEEK(horaInicio)=? OR WEEK(horaFinal)=?)";
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,id);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, week);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, week);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            List<Tech> teches = new ArrayList<>();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                Tech techFilter = getTechFromResultset(resultSet);
                teches.add(techFilter);
            }
            return teches;
        }catch (SQLException sqlException){
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Query no result by id = "+id);
        }
    }
```

[image: Aquí les muestro como me devuelve el json desde el backend]

Estaré pendiente a sus aportes o sugerencias.

Comment: Ya que estás utilizando spring boot, podrías utilizar un Repository<Tech, String> y dejar que el propio Spring te implementase el método él solito. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es modificar la clase Tech y hacer que cuando se setean las fechas llame a un método que te rellene el campo `hours`

Comment: Claro, también pensaba eso, para que al momento de retornar esos valores, ya fueran fáciles de tomar en la base de datos. Intentaré implementarlo, cualquier cosa ya estaré actualizando. Muchas gracias por tu opinión.